# htaccess mode expire override third party static assets

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, seo

while trying to optimize one website and analyzing the pagespeed insights from Google, there is a suggestion for `Leverage browser caching`

While I have already set up mod_expires header with the following line:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

<FilesMatch "^(ad_status.js|wp-emoji-release.min.js)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

In the above lines I have already included the ad_status.js for caching for 1 month.

But in the suggestion I get:

```
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js (15 minutes)
```

I couldn't find any solution how I can override this 15 minutes cache.

Comment: Unless you own doubleclick.net, I'd say it is not served by your apache?